# uiimagepickercontroller video duration - photo library

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimagepickercontroller, photolibrary

Am developing a app which will upload video to the server which is picked form local iphone photo library.

here i want to restrict the user not to upload more than 3min of video..Question is how to get the duration of the video which is picked from local photo library using uiimagepickercontroller.

will it contain any property for that..?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure but did u try `imagePickerController.videoMaximumDuration = urDuration;`

Comment: is there any way to get current playing time and pausing time in imagepicker

Answer (score 0):

You can get the size of your videofile.If you want to put check according to the size that is possible or you can get the duration by using mpmovieplayer class but for that you have to get the full video file .I dont think so you want to do this so its gud  if you can put a check according to the size.